# WSO2 DataMapper : Mapping field Error while parsing XML input stream

Tags: wso2

i want to send data that i recive it from API to datamapper then return it to the client .

Everytime i call the api it's return null but if i remove datamapper config , it's return the values .

anyway I also facing this error :
DataMapper Error : Mapping field Error while parsing XML input stream , Current context not object but root

I Try to make input file xml and output JSON but not working
Also input JSON and output JSON , not working

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDpNh.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You have not provided enough details to answer this question. Hence share all the stack traces, payloads you send, and a minimal reproducible code example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You didn't give us more details about your issue, try to make a screenshot or give us your code .You can follow the documentation about DataMapper https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/references/mediators/data-Mapper-Mediator/

Comment: @OussamaNairi please can you see the image i upload one in the quastion

Comment: give us the configuration file

Comment: Do you mean the config for DataMapper ?